# Powershell Get Latest from Nuget Feed

Tags: powershell, nuget

I am needing to create a powershell script that will pull down the latest packages from our nuget feed.  This script will run during a TeamCity build to help with a caching issue that we are having with the nuget packages.  I have not worked with powershell before, so any help would be greatly appreciated.  This is what I have so far:

```html
$packagesConfigFiles = Get-ChildItem $path -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq "packages.config"}

foreach($packagesConfig in $packagesConfigFiles){

 .\nuget.exe i $packagesConfig.FullName -o Source\Packages
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case someone needs it I wanted to post what I used for my solution.

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted 

$packagesConfigFiles = Get-ChildItem $path -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq "packages.config"}

if (Test-Path packages){

    Write-Host "Delete packages folder."
    Remove-Item packages -recurse
}

foreach($packagesConfig in $packagesConfigFiles){      

    .nuget\NuGet.exe i $packagesConfig.FullName -o packages
}

Write-Host "Press any key to continue..."
    $Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho,IncludeKeyUp") > $null
```